# How to pass error information from oracle to access

Tags: oracle, ms-access, plsql, vba

I have Oracle DB with packages in it. Also I have MS Access as frontend for this DB.

Now when I got error in oracle, in access I got only ODBC error.

Is there any solutions to pass error information (number, desc)  from Oracle to Access?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Sorry, but what is wrong in my post? I looked for answer in stackoverflow, but I didn't find any...

Comment: Questions like "how to do this?", without showing any research effort or attempt are not welcome on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop thru DBEngine.Errors collection. Error trapping should look like this:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorTrap
    ' Execute connect code at this point
Exit_errortrap:
    Exit Sub
ErrorTrap:
    Dim myerror As Error
    For Each myerror In DBEngine.Errors
        With myerror
            If .Number <> 3146 Then
                MsgBox .Description
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Resume Exit_errortrap
```